# Read multipart-form data as []byte in GO

Tags: go, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm using [GIN](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) as GO framework, I'm having an issue when uploading file and directly convert image as byte so I can store it in my BLOB field inside db table, so I have my piece of code like this:

```
func (a *AppHandler) Upload(ctx *gin.Context) {

form := &struct {
    Name    string `form:"name" validate:"required"`
    Token   string `form:"token" validate:"required"`
    AppCode string `form:"app_code" validate:"required"`
}{}
ctx.Bind(form)
if validationErrors := a.ValidationService.ValidateForm(form); validationErrors != nil {
    httpValidationErrorResponse(ctx, validationErrors)
    return
}

file, header, err := ctx.Request.FormFile("file")
```

and I'm trying to store it in db like this

```
app.SetFile(file)
a.AppStore.Save(app)
```

and it returns this kind of error:

> cannot use file (type multipart.File) as type []byte

Comment: Who was the douche that did a drive-by down vote on this? Its a clear question, with an obvious attempt via the code sample. Question helped me

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[`*multipart.File`](https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#File) implements `io.Reader` interface so you could copy its content into a bytes.Buffer like this:

```
file, header, err := ctx.Request.FormFile("file")    
defer file.Close()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

buf := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
if _, err := io.Copy(buf, file); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

and then add to your app

```
app.SetFile(buf.Bytes())
```